# Acidic Elderflower Wine

Tags: wine, acidic, country-wine

I was racking a batch of elderflower wine today and had a cheeky sample on the way to the secondary. OMG it was akin to lemon juice, I think I may have added a bit too much citric acid to the mix when making this one. It is a 1 gallon batch.

Anyone had a similar experience and how did they bring it back to palatable? I am thinking of adding a little CaCo3 to mellow it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try siphoning off a glass of the wine and adding a pinch of BiCarbonate of Soda or Calcium Carbonate, give it a good stir and see how it turns out.

Comment: Potassium carbonate can also be used - unlike Calcium Carbonate, it reacts immediately and doesn't leave a deposit. http://www.bcawa.ca/winemaking/acidph.htm